# Simulation Failed: Transactions not in Ascending Order GHDL

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fpga, vivado, ghdl

I'm trying to run a testbench and when I attempt to run the simulation I get the following error:

> ./rc_symbols_testbench:error: transactions not in ascending order
>
> ./rc_symbols_testbench:error: simulation failed
> msf_symbols.vhd rc_symbols_testbench.vhd

---

A reduced version of the testbench that still produces the error:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use STD.textio.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;

entity rc_symbols_testbench is
end;

architecture impl of rc_symbols_testbench is

    subtype byte is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    constant byte_null: byte := (others => '0');
    constant byte_unknown: byte := (others => 'X');

    constant clk_freq:   integer := 25500;
    constant clk_period: time      := (1 / (clk_freq))*sec;
    constant gate_delay: time      := 0.1 ns;
    constant t_sample:   time      := 100 ms;
        
    signal   eod:         std_logic                       :=            '0';
    signal   clk:         std_logic                       :=            '0';
    signal   rst:         std_logic                       :=            '0';
    signal   dcf_tro:     std_logic                       :=            '0';
    

begin

    process
    begin
    
        while eod = '0' loop
            clk <= not clk;
            --wait for clk_period / 2;
            wait for 19.60784314 us; --19.6us approx = clock period / 2
        end loop;
        
        wait;
    end process;
    
    rst <= '1', '0' after 150 ms;

    process
        file     data_file:   text;
        variable data_line:   line;
        variable dcf_do_var:  byte;
        variable dcf_tro_var: std_logic;
        variable dcf_so_var:  std_logic;
        variable msf_do_var:  byte;
        variable msf_tro_var: std_logic;
        variable msf_so_var:  std_logic;
        variable t_var:       time;
    begin
        file_open(data_file, "rc_symbols.dat", read_mode);

        while not endfile(data_file) loop
            readline(data_file, data_line);

            hread(data_line, dcf_do_var);
             read(data_line, dcf_so_var);
             read(data_line, dcf_tro_var);
            hread(data_line, msf_do_var);
             read(data_line, msf_so_var);
             read(data_line, msf_tro_var);

             read(data_line, t_var);

            if t_var > now then
                wait for t_var - now;
            end if;

           
            dcf_tro <= dcf_tro_var, '0' after clk_period;
           

        end loop;
        
        file_close(data_file);
        eod <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;

end;
```

I've also reduced `rc_symbols.dat` to:

```
00 0 0 FF 0 1 1736901.960861734 us
00 0 0 FF 0 0 1736941.176548008 us
0C 0 1 FF 0 0 1754705.88243013 us
0C 0 0 FF 0 0 1754745.098116404 us
0C 0 0 31 0 1 1837019.607919256 us
0C 0 0 31 0 0 1837058.82360553 us
00 0 1 31 0 0 1854823.529487652 us
00 0 0 31 0 0 1854862.745173926 us
00 0 0 00 0 1 1937137.254976778 us
00 0 0 00 0 0 1937176.470663052 us
00 0 1 00 0 0 1954901.9608589 us
00 0 0 00 0 0 1954941.176545174 us
00 0 0 00 0 1 2037215.686348026 us
00 0 0 00 0 0 2037254.9020343 us
00 0 1 00 0 0 2055019.607916422 us
00 0 0 00 0 0 2055058.823602696 us
00 0 0 00 0 1 2137333.333405548 us
00 0 0 00 0 0 2137372.549091822 us
00 0 1 00 0 0 2155137.254973944 us
```

To me, it looks like everything's in ascending order so I'm still not sure.

---

If I comment out this, it simulates, but I'm not sure how to fix the error:

```
dcf_tro <= dcf_tro_var, '0' after clk_period;
```

Comment: `Any ideas what else could be causing this problem?` Yes. (YES/NO questions can be useless to future readers, provide a [mcve]). `./rc_symbols_testbench:error: transactions not in ascending order` - occurs in your testbench while executing a signal assignment. Transactions consist of a current or future driver value and a time (the current simulation time without an **after** time_expression), see IEEE 1076-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement para 6 "It is an error if the sequence of new transactions is not in ascending order with respect to time.", 14.7.2 Drivers.

Comment: @user1155120 so do you think I'm looking at the wrong thing when getting concerned with the `Makefile`? Also, "any idea what else could be causing this" isn't really a yes/no question in the practical sense... I'll rephrase it though

Comment: @user1155120 I've also added some information that may be more relevant given what you've said

Comment: Yes. You're `looking at the wrong thing when getting concerned with the Makefile`. It's a VHDL semantic error detected during simulation. Provide a [mcve], Your edit  isn't sufficient..

Comment: @user1155120 I've stripped everything out of the testbench that's irrelevant and posted what is as close to an MRE as I can reasonably get. Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: Looks like I've found the problem, I've also edited the question to make it more useful for future users

Comment: I can't provide that package for copyright reasons... It's also known-good and not the source of the problems. It's fine, I've fixed it now, thanks for the help.

Comment: use `--std=08` and eliminate `use work.std_logic_textio.all;` They're provide in -2008 package std.textio. Alternatively in ghdl `--ieee=synopsys` and `use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;`. Supply an rc_symbols.dat to match the `file` in the code, with hex values for `dcf_do` and `msf_do`. Without those there are more errors and your solution doesn't 'teach' the problem. You could also drop everything but the read for `dcf_tro`. Enlighten your readers what the prefixes stand for?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with the `rc_symbols.dat`, it seems to work just fine now?

As for the prefixes, MSF and DCF are two different radio clock formats, I'm writing a decoder.

Comment: @user1155120 my bad... it's been a long, stressful day... I copied the wrong file... sorry

Comment: rc_symbol.dat is long... It has about 5000 lines, I just reduced it for the purposes of this example. I think it was generated from the signal from an actual radio clock to act as test data. 

Either way, I'm not sure it matters too much at this stage since I've found the problem was to do with a constant evaluating wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user1155120 for the helpful comments.

The issue lay in the fact that:

```
constant clk_period: time      := (1 / (clk_freq))*sec;
```

was evaluating in such a way that it caused a zero or negative delay. Substituting this line for:

```
constant clk_period: time      := 39.2157 us;
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: For sure, you are dividing integer `1` by integer `clk_freq` that yields `0`, always. Did you try to use floating points?

Comment: I do question why this works fine in the other test benches I've been given that use the exact same line though

Comment: So the assignment to the value of `dcf_tro_var` in the waveform for the assignment to `dcf_tro` is scheduled to occur at the time contained found in `t_var`. The second new transaction to '0' is scheduled to occur after the time specified in `clk_period` which is erroneously 0 fs. The line where the error is detected isn't the problem it's the declaration of `clk_period`. The line containing the assignment's time out clause run's afoul of the rule from 10.5.2.2 which tells us there can only only be one new transaction scheduled for a particular simulation time in a waveform.

Comment: Your [mcve] worked and reproduced the error. Diagnosing it is hard without a simulator that can be single stepped through sequential statements with variables displayed. It can be done by [instrumenting the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8GdZ.jpg) (here with report statements). You'd find that the very first assignment's second new transaction failed.